# How to do bulkupload in Cosmos DB for mongodb api

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to upload 100GB Json file to cosmos DB. I want to use mongo DB API to store the data. How can i able to bulk upload the data to cosmos DB? Is there any option provided to upload json file to cosmos db.

Comment: Is the goal for this 100GB Json file to become a single document in Cosmos? Because if so, you'll run into the [Cosmos logical partition limit (20gb)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would probably use mongoimport to do this. There are some things to configure in Cosmos DB when importing data. You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/tutorial-mongotools-cosmos-db) as well as a lot of other articles on migrating data into Cosmos DB API for MongoDB